# possible to get subscription information for subreddits/users of Reddit?

Tags: reddit, praw

I would like to see either a list of subscribers for a given subreddit or a list of subreddits to which an individual user subscribes to. Is either of these bits of information available? In the PRAW docs I see my_reddits() but that seems to mean you can only retrieve the subscription list for yourself as a logged in user.

I also see this in the Reddit API docs: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_subreddits_mine_subscriber
This also seems to assume you're looking at your own/logged-in account?

Sorry to post but I have not been able to find this in the Reddit API docs or the PRAW docs. I'd appreciate any relevant links or advice.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the account information (username/password) in order to see this information. The Reddit API does not provide a way to access this information otherwise. I had a friend who worked on a project that used this type of information and he needed to get passwords from users.

Comment: thanks for confirming. I suspected as much, but didn't find Reddit entirely explicit about it.